# Can't open Ledger nano s at MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s

I just got Ledger Nano S but can't figure out how to use it at MyEtherWallet.
My problem happens at number 3)

- 1)going to 'Send Ether & Tokens' page.
- 2)choosing 'Ledger Wallet'.
- 3)Clicking 'Connect to Ledger Wallet', but nothing happens.

I have latest firmware installed(1.3.1), and browser support enabled in Ethereum App.
It works with Ledger Wallet Ethereum(chrome), but can't figure out what's wrong with MyEtherWallet, and why it's not working.
Is it something wrong with my settings, or broken hardware?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: question is: Why would someone want to use google chrome instead of firefox? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. This solves 99% of problems.

-Restart your computer (Do not be lazy. Restart it FIRST).

- Use Google Chrome.
- Make sure you don't have any other apps that connect to your Ledger open (e.g. the Ledger Bitcoin Chrome app, Mist, etc.)
- Make sure you have browser support turned ON.
- Make sure you have contract data turned ON.
- That you are confirming any transactions via your Ledger.

Based on what you have said, I'm going to guess that you do not have browser support turned on. Browser support = on for MEW and off for the Ledger Chrome App.

If you are still having issues, please email us at support@myetherwallet.com.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now it's working perfectly without any problems!
It was because of the browser I was using,(firefox) and the popup window didn't come out by clicking 'connect to Ledger Wallet'. It worked perfect with Google Chrome. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to go setting and click browser support yes